# Launch Options on Visual Basic.NET Applications

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am attempting to set up launch options in my Visual Basic program. The trouble is, I can't figure out how to do it myself and can't find any solutions online. Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean be launch options.

Comment: `example.exe -x 2048 -y 1024 -z 512`

Comment: Ah, command line arguments. It's a project option in Visual Studio... you have to make sure you start a Main() method rather than a Form/window, and then the command line is an array argument to the method. You have to build your own code to decide how to interpret that array.

Comment: see: [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, that's not true. With the VB Application Framework enabled and the `Main` method hidden, you can still access the commandline arguments before the startup form is created in the `Startup` event handler and you can use `Environment.GetCommandlineArgs` anywhere, including in the `Load` event handler of the startup form. If you use the single-instance option in the Application Framework, you can access the commandline arguments for secondary instances in the `StartupNextInstance` event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this somewhere relevant. I assume your "relevant" place has properties X, Y and Z that are integers:

```
Dim s = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()

Try

  For i = 0 to UBound(args) - 1 Step 2
    If s(i) = "-x" Then 
      X = Convert.ToInt32(s(i+1))
    Else If s(i) = "-y" Then 
      Y = Convert.ToInt32(s(i+1))
    Else If s(i) = "-z" Then 
      Z = Convert.ToInt32(s(i+1))
    Else 

Catch ex as Exception
  'some message code here if you want
End Try

If X= 0 OrElse Y = 0 OrElse Z = 0 Then
  'some advice on using the args here
End If
```

If you want to proceed with default values, put the try inside the loop so you keep processing. If you want case insensitive matching of -x etc code for it in the If..